# setImageResource to shuffled Cards array

Tags: android, arrays, random

I am making this app that shuffles cards and displays a random card everytime the user hits the image of the current card. I made an array that contains all the images of the cards and used the 'Fisher Yates Shuffle' to shuffle the array. Here is the code I wrote:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {     

int[] cards={R.drawable.aceofspades,R.drawable.aceofhearts,R.drawable.aceofclubs};{
int i = cards.length, j, temp;

while(--i > 0){
    j = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    temp = cards[j];
    cards[i] = cards[j];
    cards[i] = temp;
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void imageClick(View view) { 

    {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDice1);
    image.setImageResource(cards); // This gives an error: change type of 'cards' to 'int'.
    }


 } 

}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to set the 'image.setImageResource'. It should be the first of the shuffled cards array, and when the user hits the card it should become the next one in the array (something like i++).
 I tried 'cards' but it gives me an error. 'cards[i]' doesn't work either. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int currentCardIndex = 0;
    int[] cards = { /* card drawables here */};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        shuffle(cards);
    }

    public void imageClick(View view) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDice1);
        image.setImageResource(cards[currentCardIndex++]);
    }

    private void shuffle(int[] array) {
        int idx, tmp;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            idx = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            tmp = array[idx];
            array[idx] = array[i];
            array[i] = tmp;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition loop never exists alone in a program put the `while loop` inside the function

something like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    while(--i > 0){
        j = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
        temp = cards[j];
        cards[i] = cards[j];
        cards[i] = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed it but it doens't solve the first problem.